# What is wrong in this math equation in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a math equation and I want use it in my program
but I got an error. The result from this equation is non number ..
the math equation i:

**note:** n is the number in the textbox

```
((298/2)^2*ACOS(((298/2)-n)/(298/2))-((298/2)-n)*((2*(298/2)*n-n^2))^(0.5))*1213/1000
```

in button code

```
double a = Math.Pow((298.00 / 2), 2);
        double b = (Math.Acos(((298.00 / 2) - Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text)) / (298.00 / 2)));
         double c = ((298.00 / 2) - Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text));
        double d = (2 * (298.00 / 2) * Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text));
        double f = Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text), 2);
        double r = ((a * b) - (c * d) )- f;
        double result = Math.Pow(r, (0.5));
        double h = result * 1213.00 / 1000;
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(h );
    }
```

If anyone knows what is wrong here, tell me please.
The error is in variable r because the result from r is less that 0!

Comment: You´re doing interger-division all over, e.g. `1213/1000` will return `1`, not `1.213`. However I´m not sure on the order of operators, chances are that `*` is evaluated before `/`, which would give you `(double * int) / int)` which **is** a `double`. However I´d make it clear by **explicitely** using `double` all over, e.g. `1213.0`.

Comment: Add decimal places to your numbers like 298 --> 298.00 OR add a "d" to label the number as a double OR if you want a float use "f"

Comment: where exactly does the error happen and what are the values of the variables then?

Comment: the error happened in variable r the result is less of 0 @ HimBromBeere

Comment: and what are the values of a, b, c, d and f when you notice that behaviour? And how does "less than zero" fit "the result from this equation is non number"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets rewrite given math expression in more convenient way:

```
( (298/2)^2 * ACOS(((298/2)-n)/(298/2)) - ((298/2)-n) * ( (2*(298/2)*n - n^2 ) ) ^ (0.5) ) * 1213/1000
  ---------   -------------------------   -----------     ------------   ---
      a                  b                     c               d          f
                                                        --------------------------------
                                                                 r = (d - f) ^ 0.5
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                    (a * b - c * r) * 1213/1000
```

Now it is easier to see that you have an error in formula:

```
double r = ((a * b) - (c * d) )- f;
```

`r` must be calculated using the next formula:

```
double r = Math.Sqrt(d - f); // It is better to use Math.Sqrt(x) instead of Math.Pow(x, 0.5).
```

Now knowing where the error is we can fix it:

```
double n = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);

double a = Math.Pow(298.00 / 2, 2);
double b = Math.Acos( (298.00 / 2 - n) / (298.00 / 2) );
double c = 298.00 / 2 - n;
double d = 2 * 298.00 / 2 * n;
double f = Math.Pow(n, 2);
double r = Math.Sqrt(d - f);
double result = a * b - c * r;
double h = result * 1213.00 / 1000;

textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(h);
```

---

But for values of `n > 298` you will still get `r = NaN` because for such values of `n` expression `d - f` is negative.

Comment: Thank you very much ^^ for help . now I know where is my mistake .